# Run Google Sheets Script at a SPECIFIC TIME

Tags: automation

I want to run a Google Sheets Script, say function xyz(), at a "specific time" every day from a Google spreadsheet.

The specific time will be defined in a specific cell in one of the spreadsheet tab. If that cell content is empty then the script shouldn't run.

Can someone help me with a sample code or point me to the appropriate link with the relevant info. Sorry I am still bootstrapping myself to learn Google sheets scripting.

Answer (score 0):

How 'timely' do you want your scripts to run?

For example, you can set it to run between a certain hour (i.e. 6am to 7am).

If you want it to run within a minute of accuracy, you can just set the script to run every minute with an if function if the current time is equal to your specify time, then run your script.